# Enzyme testing: mount vs render

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

Besides `render` uses "traversal library Cheerio"..

I've just replaced all my `mount`'s with `render`'s and it works the same.
They look similar to me.

What should I choose? Is API of those two is somehow not identical?
What are particular recommendations when to use `render` over `mount`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Render doesn't need a global DOM to be available.  So it allows the tests to be run outside of an environment like a browser. In your case, if your test cases were working before it would seem you are running the tests in a browser (since mount worked) and you wouldn't need to use render. If however, your tests were failing because there was no global DOM available, then render might be a good solution

http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/render.html

Answer (score 0):

Mount is FullDom rendering. Take a look at the official documentation for examples. From my understanding if you want to test lifecycle events such as componentDidMount you should use mount.

Docs: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html